# Найти объект JQuery $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".buddy").on("swiperight", function() {
    $(this).addClass('rotate-left').delay(700).fadeOut(1);
    lastChilde($(this))
  });

  $(".buddy").on("swipeleft", function() {
    $(this).addClass('rotate-right').delay(700).fadeOut(1);
    lastChilde($(this))
  });

  $("#nextSwipe").on("click", function() {
    let divBlock = $('.buddy').find('div#buddy.buddy').prevObject;
    divBlock.addClass('rotate-left').delay(700).fadeOut(1);
    lastChilde(divBlock.prevObject)
  });

});

function lastChilde(element) {
  if (element.is(':last-child')) {
    $('.buddy:nth-child(1)').removeClass('rotate-left rotate-right').fadeIn(300);
  } else {
    element.next().removeClass('rotate-left rotate-right').fadeIn(400);
  }
}
```

```css
.rotate-left {
  transform: rotate(30deg) scale(0.8);
  transition: 1s;
  margin-left: 400px;
  cursor: e-resize;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.rotate-right {
  transform: rotate(-30deg) scale(0.8);
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: -400px;
  cursor: w-resize;
  z-index: 10;
}

.buddy {
  display: none;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-rc1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-rc1.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="container-swipe">
  <div id="buddy" class="buddy" style="display: block;">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="buddy">
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button style="margin-top: 150px" id="nextSwipe">Дальше</button>
```

Есть ивент swiperight и swipeleft.
код

```
$(".buddy").on("swiperight", function () {
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).addClass('rotate-left').delay(700).fadeOut(1);
    lastChilde($(this))
});

$(".buddy").on("swipeleft", function () {
    $(this).addClass('rotate-right').delay(700).fadeOut(1);
    lastChilde($(this))
});
```

Работает он когда я свайплю фото. Работает хорошо, но у меня еще есть кнопка "Дальше" и она тоже должна делать свайп что и пальцем, но тут проблема, я банально не могу проследить тот же элемент что нахожу при ивенте свайпа `$(this)` Ведь у меня в `$(this)` уже будет кнопка а не фото.

```
$("#nextSwipe").on("click", function () {
    let divBlock = $('.buddy')[0]; // не дает результата
    divBlock.addClass('rotate-left').delay(700).fadeOut(1);
    lastChilde(divBlock.prevObject)
});

 <div id="nextSwipe" class="show-more">Дальше</div>
```

`let divBlock = $('.buddy')[0]` и `$(this)` в момент срабатывания свайпа дают совершено разные объекты и код дальше не применим и свайп не работает.

Пишу на всякий случай еще последнею функцию. Она начинает свайп с начала если все блоки закончились.

```
function lastChilde(element){
if (element.is(':last-child')) {
    $('.buddy:nth-child(1)').removeClass('rotate-left rotate-right').fadeIn(300);
} else {
    element.next().removeClass('rotate-left rotate-right').fadeIn(400);
}
}
```

html

```
 <div class="buddy" style="display: block;">
    <div>
      <img src="myimg/img1.png"/>
   </div>
 </div>
<div class="buddy">
    <div>
      <img src="myimg/img2.png"/>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Кнопка должна выполнить тоже самое что и свайп. Каким образом мне находить при клике по кнопке абсолютно одинаковый объект на JS/Jquery так же как и при ивенте свайпа мышкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, запустить ивент вручную по клику на кнопку:
`$('.buddy').trigger('swiperight');`

Comment: А как тогда вы  $(this) замените, в этом вся проблема

Comment: Не должен же по идее

Comment: как не должен если в this приходит кнопка а не уже блок пр которому вы свайпаете, у вас тогда кнопка засвайпетс, я вставил пример кода, попробуйте прям тут

Comment: не знаю, у меня всё работает. https://jsfiddle.net/cph90r37/

Comment: где ж у вас все работает, когда последний квадратик, то он с начала уже не начинает если вы кнопкой переключате, попробуйте свайпать мышкой по квадратику и увидите разницу. Мышкой работает коректно, кнопкой в вашем примере нет

Comment: Почему же? Изначально вопрос был о контексте `$(this)`, он прекрасно передаётся. Нужно просто немного напильником поработать, чтобы выбирался правильный элемент, ведь их 2 по селектору `.buddy`

Comment: Чтобы поставить точку в разговоре, вот рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/x209otbs/1/. желательно его переделать, определяя является ли элемент видимым, тогда не нужно будет отслеживать фигню с дополнительным классом.

Comment: Вот теперь работает корректно. Спасибо, отметил как правильно.